# Shorthand block syntax in Crystal

Tags: crystal-lang

Is it possible to use a shorthand for blocks in Crystal, e.g.

```
my_array.sort_by(&:size)
```

This attempt returns an error:

> ... expected a function type, not Symbol

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use this syntax:

```
my_array = ["123", "22", "1"]
sorted = my_array.sort_by &.size
puts sorted
=> ["1", "22", "123"]
```

Comment: Check http://crystal-lang.org/2013/09/15/to-proc.html it explains some of the reasons `&.` plays nicer than `&:`

Comment: @BrianJCardiff I wonder if this syntax is going to change because of the new [lonely operator](http://ruby-operators.herokuapp.com/#/lonely)

Comment: @dimid, I don't see the `&.` going away any time soon. we like how it feels.

Comment: @BrianJCardiff I feel like it's an unnecessary breaking change from ruby to crystal, both syntaxes could be supported